# How to import a specific rownum range of a table from Oracle data pump?

Tags: oracle

I'm using impdp of Oracle XE 11g, trying to import a specific range (in rownum) of a table from a data pump file (*.dmp).

In a basic Oracle query, we can read the data in the rownum range (my_start <= ROWNUM < my_end) using the following query,

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT t.*, ROWNUM r
  from my_table t
) WHERE r >= my_start AND r < my_end
```

by a nested query in it.

However, when writing query in parfile of impdp, I found out that the query can only contain where clause. So, we can not import the specific rownum range of data.

I want to ask following questions.

1. Is there any way to use nested select clause in impdp query?
2. If not, is there any other way to import a specific rownum range of data?

Thank you for reading my questions.

Comment: Using a subquery like that only really makes sense with an `order by`. You're trying to get a range with both lower and upper bounds, but even just with an upper bound as in the linked question (`WHERE rownum <= 100`) you'd get indeterminate rows. That version sort of makes sense, as long as you don't care which 100 rows you get. But with ordering you're essentially asking data pump to implement in-memory sorting of the entire table, which doesn't seem reasonable. *Why* do you want to do this? Are you trying to import the entire table but in chunks - and if so, why? Or something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole Ultimately, I'm trying to import a table over 100GB from a datapump file into Oracle XE limited to 11GB. So, I decided to install multiple Oracle XEs (docker containers), split the table into 10GB pieces and import them seperately. ROWNUM is the simplest spliting criteria, so I'm using it. Is there any better way to split the table?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you'll have to import the whole table and delete what you don't need.

Alternatively, alter a table and add a new column which would represent **range** you're interested in. Then, when you want to import that specific range, use the newly added column in import data pump's `QUERY` clause.

Comment: Can I alter a table before importing the whole table? If so, how can I write the query of impdp?

Comment: Altering before importing is useless. I thought of altering **before export**.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the original DB to export the DB again. The only one I have is the data pump file (*.dmp).

Comment: I see ... well, then the only option I know is to import all and delete what you don't want.

Comment: The data is too large to import the file at once into Oracle XE. Anyway, thank you for considering and answering my question!

Comment: You're welcome; sorry for not being able to help any better.